# How do I intercept all controller requests in Play 2 + Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

In the Java flavor of Play 2, there is [GlobalSettings.onRequest](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaGlobal), which can be used to intercept all incoming requests to controllers. But in the [Scala equivalent](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaGlobal), there is no onRequest handler.

I suspect this is because the Action delegation logic needed in Java isn't required in Scala, but it's rather annoying because I want to run some code on every incoming controller request.

Does anyone know how to intercept all controller requests in a Scala + Play 2 app?

Comment: It looks like in 2.1 there is GlobalSettings#doFilter, but I was hoping for a 2.0.x-compatible solution.

Answer (score 6):

override [`def onRouteRequest (request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler]`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaInterceptors) in your [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaGlobal) might be the answer you're looking for.

From the 2.0.4 api, it's called when an HTTP request has been received.

Comment: The problem with that one compared to onRequest (in Java) is that I only want to intercept controller requests, not requests for every asset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use action composition. From Play 2.4 docs (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition):

```
import play.api.mvc._

object LoggingAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    Logger.info("Calling action")
    block(request)
  }
}
```

An then in your controller:

```
def index = LoggingAction {
  Ok("Hello World")
}
```

This is what I do when I need to run code for every request. And actually you can control on which requests this is executed by using or not your custom action, as you can still do

```
def index = Action {
  Ok("Hello World")
}
```

Hope this helps you.

### EDIT

I've just read that you want a 2.0 compliant solution. This is available for Play 2.0, this is the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaActionsComposition