# How do I log request bodies with Play 2 and Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.4 with Scala. I'd like to log every incoming request (including the **request body**). How do I do this?

Edit: Expanding on discussions in comments.

If you set up a filter, you can access the RequestHeader object.

```
class LoggingFilter extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
      [...]
  }
}
```

One can also override `onRequestReceived(request: RequestHeader)` on GlobalSettings as Michał points out.

But what can be done from here in order to get the request body?

Comment: Old question, but seems there are some relevant answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834444/requestheader-doesn-t-contain-the-request-body-at-play-framework-2-0-till-now) for example.

Answer (score -1):

In play you have a class GlobalSettings which contains method onRequest.

Just create class inherit through GlobalSettings and implement logging inside this method

Comment: I don't see a onRequest method, but there's a onRequestReceived(request: RequestHeader). The problem is, I don't see how to access the request _body_ from this point, I can't find it on the RequestHeader instance. I previously tried to do this using filters, and they also get a RequestHeader object. I think the idea is that only the request headers are available at this point, and that the I might have to wait for the request body stream to be completed... I don't see how to do this though.

Comment: ok come on I see it explicitly in documentation:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/index.html

look play.GlobalSettings

Comment: Huh, you're right. I was looking at play.api.GlobalSettings, which is apparently different from play.GlobalSettings (which indeed has an onRequest()). Thanks, I'll look into this.

Comment: From this question, it looks like onRequest() is only used in the Java flavor of Play, and not in the Scala version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131398/how-do-i-intercept-all-controller-requests-in-play-2-scala