# RequestHeader doesn’t contain the request body at Play Framework 2.0 till now

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wonder, how to get a body from the request if in the [doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.RequestHeader):

```
trait RequestHeader extends AnyRef
The HTTP request header. Note that it doesn’t contain the request body yet.
```

That seems from very 2.0 version ..

Trying to get example of async handing the request's body. In order to log it to file.

```
object AccessLoggingFilter extends EssentialFilter {

      def apply(inputAction: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction { request =>

    val accessLogger = Logger("access")

    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] = { ...

  Logger.info(s"""Request:
            Body             = ${requestHeader.???} """)
```

There are some philosophical answers on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047510/access-request-body-in-essential-filter-play-framework-2) for example. But I would not call it answer..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, play doesn't allow to access the body of the request in the filter stage.

If you only want to log the body, you can create a new action for that and compose it.

This is an example from play 2.6

```
def withLogging(action: Action[AnyContent]): Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action.async(action.parser) { request =>
      request.body match {
        case AnyContentAsJson(json) => Logger.info("JSON body was: " + Json.stringify(json))
        case _ => //implement more logging of different body types
      }
      action(request)
    }
  }


  def foo = withLogging(Action.async(cc.parsers.anyContent) { implicit request =>
    // do your stuff
  }))
```

If you have only json endpoints, you can write a specific action for that.